# How to bypass TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror, node-modules

Im using react + typescript and im encountering an error in the browser that displays **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') at Object.create.A.exports**
i have seen several posts on this issue that are...

1. telling people to adjust how they import express in their ui
2. remove an auto import from react or their ide like vscode.

I am using vscode as my ide but im not using express on the ui and i did a global search and i only have any mention of express in my node modules, its not anywhere in any components.

I'm also using crypto-browserify to run in the ui since crypto doesnt run in the ui, not sure if that info helps.

I'd like to know if anyone else has encountered this problem and if so did they find the root of the problem or a way to bypass it?

i tried deleting node modules and running npm install. I searched through the code to find any declarations for express or response that may have been autogenerated but i have yet to find the solution.

Comment: you should enable a source map to hopefully be able to see where the call is coming from in your own code.

Comment: its coming from a minified file which isnt giving much clarity

Comment: Yes that's what source maps can do, they can map a minified file to the source code that generated it (obviously you should only use them in development). It can at least tell you which part of your own code is responsible for calling that code if it's deep in a 3rd party library